# Find the probability that event $A$ is right before $B$.

Tags: probability, problem-solving

Problem: Let $S$ be a sample space of an experiment and $S = \left\lbrace A,B,C\right\rbrace $, where $P(A)=p$, $P(B)=q$, and $P(C)=r$. The experiment is repeated infinitely, and it is assumed that the successive experiments are independent. Find the probability of the event that $A$ occurs right before $B$.

Solution (given in the book): Suppose that $A$ occurs for the first time at the $n$-th trial of the experiment. If $A$ is to have occurred before $B$, then $C$ must have occurred on the first $(n-1)$ trials. Let $D$ be the event that $A$ occurs right before $B$. Then
$$D=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$$
where $D_n$ is the event that $C$ occurs on the first $(n-1)$ trials and $A$ occurs on the $n$-th trial. Since $D_n$'s are mutually exclusive (you cannot have two different sequences as one event), we have
$$ P(D)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(D_n)$$
Since the trials are independent, we have
$$ P(D_n) = [P(C)]^{n-1}P(A) = r^{n-1}p$$
Thus
$$ P(D) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^{n-1} p = p \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k = \frac{p}{1-r} $$

Question: My way of thinking was really close to that provided in the solution. However, I do not completely understand why $P(D_n)$ does not have $P(B)$ in it? Since we are looking for all sequences where $B$ is preceded by $A$, we are looking for any sequence where we have any number of $C$ (can be even zero), then followed by $A$ and then by $B$. Therefore, an event that we are interested in, has probability:
$$ P(D_n) = [P(C)]^{n-1}P(A)P(B) = r^{n-1}pq$$
where $n$ can be any natural number from $1$ to infinity, i.e. $A$ has position $n$ in the sequence and it is directly followed by $B$ at position $(n+1)$. So, in my solution the final answer is only slightly different from that from the book. We are summing over all possible infinite sequences of experiments, where $A$ can be at any position $n \in \left\lbrace 1,\dots,\infty \right\rbrace$ and is directly followed by $B$ at position $(n+1)$:
$$ P(D) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^{n-1} p q = p q\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k = \frac{p q}{1-r} $$

To summarize: why doesn't solution in the book have $P(B)$ component when determining $P(D_n)$?

Comment: The wording of the problem is not clear to me. I do not know what $A$ occurs right before $B$ means, Is it that the first occurrence of $A$ comes immediately before the first occurrence of $B$? Or that $A$ comes immediately before $B$ at some time? Or something else? I find it hard to imagine that a book would have such imprecise wording.

Comment: I think you may have made a transcription error: "right before" should say "before" and the meaning is that the first $B$ can occur on any trial after the first $A$. Once you have $CCC\ldots CA$, a $B$ will follow sometime after that with probability $1$. The book's solution is correct.

Comment: @MickA you are actually right, the book just says "before" and not "right before". However, how can we be sure that $B$ will occur in this case when there is also a possibility that it will never occur?

Comment: @MickA is my logic and solution applicable if we assume the "right before" condition? The authors proceed to use results from this problem to the next one, where they use the formula to calculate probability of events immediately following one another. So I am kind of confused as how to interpret this "$A$ happens before $B$" statement?

Comment: Probability of $B$ not occurring in $n$ consecutive tosses is $(1-q)^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$. So $B$ will occur "almost surely". Yes, your working is correct if we change it to "right before" meaning the first $A$ is followed by $B$ at the next trial.